# Не запускается программа keyboard

Tags: python, клавиатура

Сама программа работает, но если вставить следующий код:

```
import keyboard

whileer = True

while whileer:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("enter"):
        cmd()
```

то она не запускается вообще. Вот полный код:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
import sys
import keyboard



def cmd():
    x = enter.get()
    if x == "Hello":
        text.insert(1.0, "hi")

window = Tk()
window.geometry("720x480")
window.resizable(False, False)
window.configure(bg="grey")
window.title("lorem ipsum")



text = Text(window, bg="black", fg="green")
text.pack()
text.place(x=0, y=0, width=720, height=460)

enter = Entry(window, bg="grey")
enter.place(x=20, y=460, width=630, height=20)

textoncmd = Label(window, text=">", bg="grey")
textoncmd.place(x=2, y=459)

btn = Button(window, text="Отправить", command=cmd)
btn.place(x=652, y=459, height=22)

whileer = True

while whileer:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("enter"):
        cmd()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта часть вашего кода, т.е.

```
whileer = True

while whileer:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("enter"):
        cmd()
```

создает *бесконечный цикл,* потому что значение `True` переменной `whileer` вы нигде не изменяете. Значит что следующая команда

```
window.mainloop()
```

никогда не выполнится, и ваше графическое окно никогда не откроится.